# A/C reverse engineering remote control checksum

Tags: reverse-engineering

I've been trying to reverse engineer an air conditioner remote control, have done most of it but can't figure out the logic behind the checksum (well, i believe it is a checksum). I've found several ways of getting the checksum but none of them seems to work, in my case. It's a 14 bytes protocol, this is the data ive got so far (using an arduino and a tsop1838 ir receiver):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jha8m7vcty48oqg/bin.txt

3rd bit in the 6th byte turns the ac on or off (1 for on and 0 for off)

4 first bits in the 7th byte are for mode

4 first bits in the 8th byte are for temperature

3 first bits in the 9th byte are for fan

4th, 5th, 6th in the 9th byte are for swing

and i believe the last byte is the checksum. could anybody help me with that?

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure 7 lines is enough to reconstruct the checksum formula?

Comment: how many do you think i should get? got 10 more

Comment: Just thought that you could set up a system of equations over some finite field to determine the coefficients of the CRC polynomial. And you would want it to be at least well determined.